# Moving files under python

Tags: python, windows, move

I'm confused with file moving under python.
Under windows commandline, if i have directory c:\a and a directory c:\b, i can do

```
move c:\a c:\b
```

which moves a to b result is directory structure c:\b\a

If I try this with os.rename or shutil.move:

```
os.rename("c:/a", "c:/b")
```

I get

```
WindowsError: [Error 17] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

If I move a single file under c:\a, it works.

In python how do i move a directory to another existing directory?

Comment: do you want to move all contents of the directory to another directory or move the directory itself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
os.rename("c:/a", "c:/b/a")
```

is equivalent to

```
move c:\a c:\b
```

under windows commandline

Answer (score 7):

You can try using the [Shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#module-shutil) module.

Comment: Specifically shutil.move(srcFile, destFile)

Answer (score 1):

os.rename("c:/a/", "c:/b"/) --> Changes the name of folder a in folder b

os.rename("c:/a/", "c:/b/a") --> Put folder b into folder a

Answer (score 0):

When i need many file system operations I prefer using 'path' module:
**http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py/2.2**

It's quite a good and lightweight wrapper around built-in 'os.path' module.

Also code:

```
last_part = os.path.split(src)[1]
```

is a bit strange, cause there is special function for this:

```
last_part = os.path.basename(src)
```

Comment: Excellent point -- forgot about basename. I don't like how there's more than one way to do that. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to state the full path it's being moved to:

```
src = 'C:\a'
dst_dir = 'C:\b'
last_part = os.path.split(src)[1]
os.rename(src, os.path.join(dst_dir, last_part))
```

Actually, it looks like `shutil.move` will do what you want by looking at its documentation:

> If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, the
>   source
>   is moved inside the directory.

(And its [source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/shutil.py?view=markup).)

Comment: Unfortuneatly this will fail if the files are located on different volumes.

Comment: @wuub: What makes you say that? The docs say there's quirky behavior in some UNIX filesystems, but the OP is talking about Windows.

Comment: Hmm, this is straightforward for a single directory, but moving a big directory structure to another folder is really inconvenient this way. Quite strange that python doesn't support this.

Comment: It does -- shutil.move you can use via: import shutil; shutil.move(src, dst)

Comment: @cdleary: You're right, I advice against os.rename because of past problems I had with it while coding a toy FUSE filesystem, shutil on the other hand works great no matter what the OS is.

Answer (score -1):

Using Twisted's [FilePath](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.python.filepath.FilePath.html):

```
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
FilePath("c:/a").moveTo(FilePath("c:/b/a"))
```

or, more generally:

```
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
def moveToExistingDir(fileOrDir, existingDir):
    fileOrDir.moveTo(existingDir.child(fileOrDir.basename()))
moveToExistingDir(FilePath("c:/a"), FilePath("c:/b"))
```